# cin.Getline returns nothing

Tags: c++, string, cin

I am trying to learn c++. I am on strings now.
I have written this simple method that should ask to input a string and then return it. To do so I am using cin.getLine() method but the string is not printed after I use cin.getLine()

```
string getString(char string[])
{

  cout << "Please enter a string to process ";
  cin >> string;
  cout << "String in getString before process: " << string << "\n";
  cin.getline(string, STRINGSIZE);
  cout << "String after processing: " << string << "\n"; // here string is not printed
  return string;
}
```

Can anybody help me to understand what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: How do you call this function? Does `string` point to a valid and big enough memory area? why the symbol name `string` it just confuses someone who sees your code with `std::string`. Does this even compile?

Comment: Why are you reading stuff twice from `cin` into `string`?

Comment: What's the value of STRINGSIZE and what is your test input?

Comment: Yeah it does compile. I call the method in my main. STRINGSIZE  = 100. It is a constant I have declared. I can change the name string, with word[]. Maybe the problem is like @Mat has pointed out I am reading twice. I got rid of the first cin and it seems ok

Comment: @lucaConfa or get rid of getline, see my answer

Comment: @cf16 I was trying to learn how cin.getline works....

Comment: @lucaConfa so thing to remember after this lesson is you use either 'cin>>' or 'getline()' not both simultaneously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are first reading string to `std::string` with `cin >> string;` and then read again something from `cin` with `cin.getline(string, STREAMSIZE);`
it is not necessary, read it once and return:

```
string getString(char string[]){
  cout << "Please enter a string to process ";
  cin >> string;
  cout << "String in getString before process: " << string << "\n";
  // process this, do whatever you describe as processing it
  cout << "String after processing: " << string << "\n"; // string is printed
  return string;
 }
```

otherwise, if you want to use `getline`, do:

```
  std::string name;

  std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
  std::getline (std::cin,name); // or std::getline(std::cin,string, 'r'); to read
  //only to delimiter character 'r'
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
```

so thing to remember is use `getline` OR `cin`, not both simultaneously unless there is really some special reason